How to set font for UnityEngine.UI.Text in code at runtime
I'm making a localization mod for an existing Unity game, which means I have no access to the editor, everything must be done purely in code, and I can't modify any bundles or prefab resources (the game will check CRC for those), everything I need must be loaded at runtime from disk.
I've successfully loaded a font from disk and made it work for text objects that are using TextMeshPro, but it didn't work for UnityEngine.UI.Text
This fix worked for TextMeshPro (used to display blank rectangles before the fix):
UnityEngine.Font NewFont = new Font("D:/some_folder/test_font.ttf");
TMP_FontAsset NewFontAsset = TMP_FontAsset.CreateFontAsset(NewFont);
TMP_Settings.fallbackFontAssets.Add(NewFontAsset);

But this didn't work for UnityEngine.UI.Text. When this is code applied, all corresponding text just completely disappears, like not even displaying blank rectangles
UnityEngine.UI.Text SomeGameText = ...;
UnityEngine.Font NewFont = new Font("D:/some_folder/test_font.ttf");
SomeGameText.font = NewFont;

I tried assigning material from the old font, and also I tried calling SomeGameText.font.RequestCharactersInTexture(characters), none of which had any effect
Am I missing something here? How does Unity engine handle font in UnityEngine.UI.Text? How should I set the font?
Unity engine version is 2020.3.26f1

You need to set the character info on the font.  The string you passed in the constructor is just the name.  Font Constructor  Font does have a static method for creating a Font object from OS installed fonts.

I tried it out and CreateDynamicFontFromOSFont worked this time with the font's English name, it didn't work last time because I passed the font's localized name (seen in the system font settings) instead of its English name. I used to think that a font's English name and localized name are always interchangeable, looks like I was wrong.
